# Weird S3 performance on one of our buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have several different S3 buckets.  They are all setup in the same region (South Africa, Cape Town).  We recently created another bucket and though it looks like we've used the exact same settings as the other buckets in terms of configuration, the performance on the new bucket is really bad (upload speeds is less then 20KB/s, while uploading the same data to another bucket we are getting several MB/s.

Thinking it may have had something to do with the name (we used a - in the new bucket), we've deleted it and recreated a new bucket again from scratch with the same parameters as one of our other buckets, (this time replacing the - with a .).  The same performance issue on the new-new bucket.

I use TNTDrive to map the drives (on several pc's, including an EC instance in the same region) and I am getting the same weird performance.  Is there any setting that I may be missing?  The fact that I am getting reasonable speeds on the same pc/network etc on other buckets tells me it is something specific to the new bucket.

any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Well, the obvious reason would be location of the S3 bucket but you've triple-checked that. Have you done any tests outside of tntdrive, e.g. with awscli?

Comment: it is definately the same region yes.  Checking it using S3 Browser I am getting the performance as expected, it is only in TNT Drive that I am having poor performance